# Asking python for a breakfast menu

Tags: python-3.x

```
'meals = ("Juice", "Milk", "Bread")
name = input("What do you want in a breakfast? ")
if meals =='bread''milk''juice':
print("I love it ")
```

else:
    print(" I don't want it ")'

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This does not appear to be a question, please see our [help center on how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare the user input, which is a string stored in the variable `name` with `meals` which is a tuple of strings. To compare the two, you need to include a `in` logical operator:

`name = input("What do you want in a breakfast? ")
if name in meals:
    print("i love it")
else:
    print("i dont want it")`

However, for this code to work, the user input must always be capitalized. Next time, ask a question and state your desired outcome instead of just posting code.